# Filter list in R base on attribute names

Tags: r, dataframe, list, filter

I have a list of lists with the following structure:

```
List of 3
$info   :'data.frame':  21 obs. of  2 variables:
..$names  : chr [1:21] "Country1" "Country2"...
..$group   : chr [1:21] "Europe" "Europe"...

$stat: List of 1
..$notreal num [1:31579, 1:18] NA -2.50e-06 2.30e-06 -9.47e-07 1.54e-07 ...
.. .. - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. .. ..$ : chr [1:31579] "run_1" "run_2" "run_3" ...
.. .. ..$ : par [1:18] "a" "b" "c" ....

$calculations      : num [1:31579, 1:61] 0.0754 0.0089 0.0571 0.0309 0.0955 
..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. ..$ : chr [1:31579] "run_1" "run_2" "run_3"
 .. ..$ : Named chr [1:61] "aa" "bb" "cc"
```

I need to first figure out which runs have NA in $stat$notreal.

I did it using names(which(is.na($stat$notreal[,"a"])))

Then using this list of runs I need to filter them out in both Data$stat$notreal and Data$calculations (as their attributed row numbers are the same).

I am struggling to do the second part.

Comment: Feel free to share some sample data and a description of your desired output

Comment: save the indices `i <- which(is.na($stat$notreal[,"a"]))` and use that to grab the `names(...)[i]` then remove those `notreal[-i]`

Comment: @rawr Hi, thanks for your help! sorry, did not understand what command is this? names(...)[i]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the desired output. You can simple subset the data with the inverse `!` of the logical vector. There are more similar options, e.g. using `names` or indices.

```
i <- is.na(Data$stat$notreal[,"a"])

Data$stat$notreal[!i,]
#             a        b c
#run_2 -2.5e-06 1.54e-07 3
#run_3  2.3e-06 1.00e+00 4

Data$calculations[!i,]
#          aa     bb cc
#run_2 0.0089 0.0955  3
#run_3 0.0571 1.0000  4
```

Data

```
Data <- list(info = data.frame(names = c("Country1", "Country2"), group = c("Europe", "Europe")),
             stat = list(notreal = matrix(c(NA, -2.50e-06, 2.30e-06, -9.47e-07, 1.54e-07, 1:4), 3, 3, dimnames=list(c("run_1", "run_2", "run_3"), c("a", "b", "c")))),
             calculations = matrix(c(0.0754, 0.0089, 0.0571, 0.0309, 0.0955, 1:4), 3, 3, dimnames=list(c("run_1", "run_2", "run_3"), c("aa", "bb", "cc")))
             )
```